# How to cast a dictionary [String:Bool] to an array [String] in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I'm trying to cast a dictionary of [String:Bool] to an array of string.

my code is:

```
var action = [Nourishing:true, Radiance:true]
let actionArray = [action.keys.description] as? [String]
```

but the result comes out as:

```
["[\"Nourishing\", \"Radiance\"]"]
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this directly

```
let actionArray = Array(action.keys)
```

Comment: You would need to initialize a new Array `let actionArray =  Array(action.keys)`

Comment: Dictionary Keys Conforms to collection but it doesn't conform to RandomAccessCollection. A collection it is not an array.

Comment: Yes, right i surprised why it's not inferred as **[String]** despite in print it looks the same

Comment: An alternative is to  get the keys sorted. `let actionArray =  action.keys.sorted()`